# How do you automatically set to SublimeRepL as a default build system in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I installed this Build System Called SublimeRepL, but everytime I press Ctrl + Shift + B on the app(Sublime text) I get prompted for build system(which one should I choose) I want to just set it default so I don't have to choose a build system everytime manually

Comment: You can do it by going to **Tools>Build System>(and select the system)**

Comment: Note also that using `Build With...` (the keyboard shortcut you're using) also prompts Sublime to ask you what build to use when there are multiple possible builds (such as variants); you may want to just use `Build` instead.